# Where can I find Site Output Cache in WSS?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, wss

Where can i find SiteOutput cache in wss??

I did't find under site administration ...do i need to enable any feature?

Please held me out how can i do site caching in WSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully it will be helpful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa661294(v=office.12).aspx